# Windows Phone 8 SDK Integration with Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

Tags: windows-phone-8

So I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate installed. I installed the WP8 SDK but it installed the express edition for Windows Phone and it requires a second registration and a product key. I mean, why does that happen? I already have registered the Ultimate VS. Why do I need a second product key? I know its free, but... why?

Also, whenever I update something on VS Ultimate, I have to re-update it again on the express edition.

I mean, why all this mess? Is it just me?

Comment: Could you please make the question less broad and more clear?

Comment: Long story short. I have VS Ultimate installed and registered. When I installed the WP8 SDK, VS asked me to register the product again. Even though I had the ultimate version registered.

Comment: So the WP8 SDK messed up your VS registration? There is this text in the description page: `The Windows Phone SDK provides a stand-alone Visual Studio Express 2012 edition for Windows Phone or works as an add-in to Visual Studio 2012 Professional, Premium or Ultimate editions.` Are you sure you have installed the correct version (or as a plugin instead of standalone app)?

Comment: Yes, whenever I launch the stand-alone Visual studio express 2012 for windows phone it asks me to register it or else it will expire in a few days. Why would I have to register it since I already have the ultimate version registered? And what is going to happen if the stand-alone express edition expires?

Comment: It says there on the description page that you must have an option to install the SDK as add-in to your VS pro, premium or ultimate. You should do that.

Comment: No, there isn't any option like that. Whenever you install the SDK it automaticly installs a seperate version of VS also. You can't just install the SDK as an add-in without installing the VS Express for WP.

The weird thing is why it requires a second registration since I already have the Ultimate version registered.

Comment: I'd recommend looking specifically for an add-in installation, assuming there is one.

Comment: No. The WP8 SDK is the same and whenever you install it.Besides the integrated WP8 SDK to the paid version of VS, it automaticly installs the express edition for windows phone. My question is why do I have to register the express edition too since I have the registered Ultimate version of VS. It's a little complicated.

Comment: I think your problem now becomes finding a way to only install an add-in of WP8 SDK to an existing VS installation. You might want to post such a question.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem on WP7 SDK and VS 2010, i solved problem by downloading and directly installing ISO image of SDK.

Comment: Yes, it works! I had downloaded iso from MSDN subscriptions and installed it. So now I see ability to create new projects for Windows Phone.
However at present I have Visual Studion 2012 Express installed.